# Отметить все чекбоксы родительского уровня при отметке дочернего

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Самописный движок, куча чекбоксов выводится следующим образом:

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-current="101" data-parent="100" data-level="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="256" data-parent="101" data-level="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="1234" data-parent="256" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="1236" data-parent="256" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="2274" data-parent="1236" data-level="4" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="257" data-parent="101" data-level="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="7434" data-parent="257" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="102" data-parent="100" data-level="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="336" data-parent="102" data-level="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="7458" data-parent="336" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
<input type="checkbox" data-current="9800" data-parent="336" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">
```

Видно, что у списка чекбоксов соблюдается структура. Есть чекбоксы 1-го уровня `data-level="1"`, второго и тд. Также у каждого чекбокса есть его айди `data-current`, и айди родителя `data-parent`.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы при отметке любого чекбокса, автоматически отмечался его родитель, а также родители родителя, если они есть. Желательно также, чтобы при снятии отметки с родителя, снимались все отметки с его дочерних.
Спасибо.

Comment: И что у вас не получилось? Покажите ваш код, с которым возникли сложности и опишите вашу проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться [делегацией события](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) (это сильно снизит нагрузку, т.к. не будем на каждый `input` вешать слушатель):

1. Оборачиваем все инпуты в один большой контейнер. Обёртка в дополнительный `label` был сделан чисто для удобства стилизации
2. Вешаем слушателя на событие клик (`inputsContainer.addEventListener('click'`) на, обёртывающий все инпуты, контейнер
3. Далее убеждаемся что мы нажали именно на наш `checkbox` (`target.type !== 'checkbox'`)
4. Далее в зависимости от значения `checkbox`-а (`newState`) выполняем один из двух действий (`action`):

   - Если мы выбрали, то запускаем функцию (`activateAllParents`), которая найдёт все нужные родительские элементы и выберет их
   - Если мы сняли выбор, то запускаем функцию (`deactivateAllChildren`), которая найдёт все нужные дочерние элементы и у всех снимет выбор

Теперь разберёмся в том как работают наши функции `activateAllParents` и `deactivateAllChildren`

Начнём с `activateAllParents`:

1. На вход ожидается нажатый `checkbox`, от которого мы и будем отталкиваться
2. Находим его родителя, с помощью функции `getParent`

   2.1. По данной структуре, родителем для элемента считается тот, у кого аттрибут `data-current` равен аттрибуту `data-parent`, у самого элемента. Следовательно нужно достать значение аттрибута `data-parent` у самого элемента (`child.dataset.parent`) и сделать поиск внутри контейнера (`inputsContainer.querySelector`) и найти того, у кого в `data-current` написано то же самое (`[data-current="${child.dataset.parent}"]`). Выбран метод `querySelector` потому что у элемента, не может больше одного родителя
3. Далее запускаем цикл (`while`), который запускает ряд дейтсвий до тех пор пока родитель находится (`parent !== null`):

   3.1. Если родитль уже выбран (`parent.checked === true`), то нет смысла идти дальше вверх по цепочке, потому можно завершить работу функции

   3.2. Выбираем родителя (`parent.checked = true`)

   3.3. Ищем родителя родителя (`parent = getParent(parent)`)

Теперь рассмотрим `deactivateAllChildren`:

1. На вход ожидается нажатый checkbox, от которого мы и будем отталкиваться
2. Находим все его дочерние элементы, с помощью функции `getAllChildren`

   2.1. По данной структуре, дочерними для элемента считаются те, у которых аттрибут `data-parent` равен аттрибуту `data-current`, у самого элемента. Следовательно нужно достать значение аттрибута `data-current` у самого элемента (`parent.dataset.current`) и сделать поиск внутри контейнера (`inputsContainer.querySelectorAll`) и найти тех, у которых в `data-parent` написано то же самое (`[data-parent="${parent.dataset.current}"]`). Выбран метод `querySelectorAll` потому что у элемента, может больше одного дочернего элемента
3. Проходимся по всем дочерним элементам `children.forEach`

   3.1. Если дочерний элемент и так уже не выбран (`child.checked === false`), то нет смысла идти дальше вглубь, потому можно завершить работу для этого дочернего элемента

   3.2. Убираем выбор у дочернего (`child.checked = false`)

   3.3. Рекурсивно убираем выбор у всех дочерних элементов данного дочернего элемента (`deactivateAllChildren(child)`)

Про `dataset` можете прочитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Конечный результат:

```js
const inputsContainer = document.querySelector('.inputs');

const getParent = child => inputsContainer.querySelector(`[data-current="${child.dataset.parent}"]`);
const getAllChildren = parent => inputsContainer.querySelectorAll(`[data-parent="${parent.dataset.current}"]`);

const activateAllParents = child => {
  let parent = getParent(child);

  while (parent !== null) {
    if (parent.checked === true) return;
    
    parent.checked = true;

    parent = getParent(parent);
  }
}

const deactivateAllChildren = parent => {
  const children = getAllChildren(parent);

  children.forEach(child => {
    if (child.checked === false) return;
  
    child.checked = false;

    deactivateAllChildren(child);
  })
}

inputsContainer.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const target = e.target;

  if (target.type !== 'checkbox') return;

  const newState = target.checked;
  const action = newState ? activateAllParents : deactivateAllChildren;

  action(target);
})
```

```css
.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="101" data-parent="100" data-level="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="256" data-parent="101" data-level="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1.1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="1234" data-parent="256" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1.1.1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="1236" data-parent="256" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1.1.2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="2274" data-parent="1236" data-level="4" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1.1.2.1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="257" data-parent="101" data-level="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1.2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="7434" data-parent="257" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">1.2.1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="102" data-parent="100" data-level="1" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="336" data-parent="102" data-level="2" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">2.1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="7458" data-parent="336" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">2.1.1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-current="9800" data-parent="336" data-level="3" name="checkboxes[]" value="NNN">2.1.2
  </label>
</div>
```